# Does my elasticsearch callee method needs to be threadsafe?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, thread-safety

I am using RestHighLevelClient provided in elastic search java library. As per documentation, this class is threadsafe. I am using create index function inside a method. Do I need to specifically made that thread safe?

Or in general, if the objects used by a java method are threadsafe, then does it make sense to make method thread safe?

Comment: What do you mean by "make method thread safe"?

Comment: @Malt Means making only one execution of function at a time. `public synchronized void createIndex() {}`

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to specifically made that thread safe?

Since you seem to mean making the method synchronized, the answer is no. "Thread-safe" means that the methods of the class can be safely invoked from multiple threads **without** external synchronization like the one you propose.